# Jenkins pipeline to return results-file after build

Tags: jenkins, build, jenkins-pipeline, devops, jobs

I'm running a few tests in my pipeline, results are written to a few `.txt` files.

Is it possible to upload the *.txt files* to the jenkins job?

Meaning that the person running the pipeline will receive the results in the browser, and simply download them.

> note - junit could have provide a suitable solution, but im not working with XML but with simple *txt files*

Comment: You need the `archiveArtifacts` step in your pipeline. See https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/core/ and https://medium.com/@gustavo.guss/jenkins-archive-artifact-save-file-in-pipeline-ac6d8b569c2c.

Answer (score 0):

use `archiveArtifacts 'myfile.txt'`

https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/tests-and-artifacts/

Also have a look at the links shared by Dibakar.
If you want to go further, I would recommend to record your test results on another system than jenkins because usually we keep a limited numbers of builds on jenkins. A standard solution is to use sonarqube (there is a Jenkins plugin to help you upload test result on sonar) but you could also upload your results to a database like influxdb (with jenkins influxdb plugin)